# Getting "Cannot Run the Macro..." Error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I recently learned how to program in VBA and have gotten some extremely helpful assistance by reading through the previously asked questions and answers on this site. However, I have encountered a problem in one of my programs that doesn't appear to be addressed very directly. So I'll ask it here.

I am making a Powerpoint macro that will automatically update some slides with new data. For one slide that contains an excel table, I want the macro to open up an excel file, run an existing macro in the excel file to populate the spreadsheet with new data, and finally copy the table over to the powerpoint slide. My code so far (without the copy over portion) is this:

```
Private Sub GetProposals()
    Dim myXL As Excel.Application
    Dim myXLS As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set myXL = New Excel.Application
    Set myXLS = GetObject("K:\Jackson\Proposal Summary Master.xlsm")
    Set ws = myXLS.Sheets(1)
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    myXLS.Sheets("VLOOKUP").Range("J1").Value = "EPL"
    myXL.Run ("'K:\Jackson\Proposal Summary Master.xlsm'!BABox_Change")
End Sub
```

It runs correctly until I reach the "myXL.Run..." line. I get a message saying "Run-time error '1004': Cannot run the macro "K:\Jackson\Proposal Summary Master.xlsm'!BABox_Change'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled."

The excel macro runs fine when I open up the file directly and start it that way. I am somewhat stuck on what I should do next. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: It could be very tricky when calling macros in other file in another app. You should make the Excel to Open that file before trying to call that macro. And remove the folder path in the .Run argument. Depends on how the macro in Master.xlsm is written, it may not produce anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue may be because you're not opening the workbook. The key to this though, would be to make sure that the objects are released after the code is executed; that way, the file isn't "locked" by your powerpoint file or extra 'hidden' processes/instances of Excel are left open.

```
Private Sub GetProposals()
    Dim myXL As Excel.Application
    Dim myXLS As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set myXL = New Excel.Application
    Set myXLS = myXL.Workbooks.Open("K:\Jackson\Proposal Summary Master.xlsm")
    myXLS.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set ws = myXLS.Sheets(1)
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden

    myXLS.Sheets("VLOOKUP").Range("J1").Value = "EPL"
    myXLS.Application.Run ("BABox_Change")

    myXLS.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    myXLS.Close(true) ' Change to false if you don't want to save Changes


    Set myXLS = Nothing
    Set myXL = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant. that worked for me as well. I just adapted the portion

```
   myXLS.Sheets("VLOOKUP").Range("J1").Value = "EPL"
        myXLS.Application.Run ("BABox_Change")
```

to my files